# Configuration for newLine for block parameter in Uncrustify formatter

Tags: objective-c, format, uncrustify

I want to know as if there exists configuration in Uncrustify, so that following formatting(or at least some part of it) can be achieved(language is objective-c).

Original code:

```
@interface BaseVideoViewController : BaseViewController    <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, CircleTransitionFromController, PassiveUserGifCellDelegate, PassiveUserCollectionViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray   <TokBoxParticipants *> *currentPassivePlayersArray;

@interface BaseVideoViewController   ()   {

    NSMutableArray  <NSString *> *passiveUserForCellList;

}

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 parama1:2.0 animations:^{
                     // oc_block should come down if in same line by formatter
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // something
                 }];

    switch (something.state) {
        case 0: {}
        Break;

    }

if  (_voiceTextView == nil)   {
```

Desired code after formatting:

```
@interface BaseVideoViewController: BaseViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, CircleTransitionFromController, PassiveUserGifCellDelegate, PassiveUserCollectionViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <TokBoxParticipants *> *currentPassivePlayersArray;

@interface BaseVideoViewController() {

    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *passiveUserForCellList;

}


[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 parama1:2.0 
                   animations:^{
                     // oc_block should come down if in same line by formatter
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // something
                 }];

 switch (something.state) {
        case 0: {
             Break;
        }   



    }

if (_voiceTextView == nil) {
```

Changes which need to be observed after formatting:

1. There is space between 'if' and '(', but I don't want space between 'BaseVideoViewController' and '('.
2. I dont want space between interface name i.e. 'BaseVideoViewController' and ':'.
3. I want space between data-type and angular bracket('<') in interface or property definition, but not at other places in code.
4. Notice the change in break statement.
5. When calling function, I want parameters to come into new line, if that parameter has value starting from '^'(parameter named animations, completions in above code).

Answer (score 1):

Uncrustify-0.65-106-95188777

1. It does not seem like there is an option for that currently
2. `sp_before_class_colon = remove`
3. See 1, there are however (way) more generic options like for example `sp_before_angle` and `sp_inside_angle`
4. `mod_move_case_break   = true` should do that, but it does not seem to work for **OC**. It also does not work with your example for **C++** unless `Break` is changed to `break` and the closing brace is on its own line.
5. See 1

Submit Feature and Pull requests to the [Uncrustify git repo](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify)

Comment: Thanks for your input and time. Can you please look this question[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772985/uncrustify-objective-c-parameter-value-alignment-indentation) also related to uncrustify.